# Trek Mamba 2013, what BB and crankset for 1x?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, trek

Can anyone help me to find which kind of BB and cranks do I need for an 1x11 upgrade.

Comment: Suggest you look at the bike yourself. There will be part numbers on the shifters, rd, fd, crankset. Also the cassette at the back . Edit your post with these specs. This can vary within a year from a manufacturer, yours might have  been replaced. This is the only reliable way to do this. Anything else is a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to know with respect to compatibility is what bottom bracket your frame can accommodate.

This [old Bike Radar review](https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/bikes/mountain-bikes/trek-mamba-review/?image=3&type=gallery&gallery=1) says the Mamba has an ‘3 piece’ crank and Octalink cartridge BB as standard, which means the frame is a threaded shell type either 68 or 73mm wide.

Your easiest path forward is to get a ‘2 piece’ crank that uses external threaded BB cups and is compatible with 68 or 73mm frame shells. There are plenty of 1x cranks available that work with external bearings in the frame widths.

Note the BB cups have to match the crank axle, each manufacturer has their own standard for axle and bearing sizes. The threads in the frame are standardized though and known as ‘ISO’ or ‘English’ threads.

It’s not practical to cite a few suitable crank models because 1) product recommendations are off-topic here and 2) there are actually a large array of cranks from different manufacturers that will work. To start you off though:

- Shimano cranks use a 24mm axle and all work with their ‘Hollowtech II’ threaded BB cups (as well as press-fit BB types).
- SRAM offers cranks that are either 24/22mm axle that work with ‘GXP’ threaded cups, or 30mm axles that work with press-fit BBs.

If you want to understand Shimano’s products their [product line-up charts](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc) are a really good place to start (Shimano is undoubtedly the best groupset manufacturer at providing documentation). This tells you what components work together and provides links to specifications.

Comment: Can you post few models of both BB and compatible cranksets, I really don't know what to look at

Comment: See updates above.

Comment: Thank you!! Accepted.

Comment: @davidm see further updates also

Comment: SRAM cranks either use 24mmDS/22mmNDS GXP (outdated), or 28.99mm DUB. Other brands like RaceFace use the 30mm axle.

Comment: @MaplePanda good point on DUB

Comment: @MaplePanda would this two fit: [BB](https://www.bike24.com/p2100222.html) and [cranksets](https://www.bike24.com/p2372227.html)

Comment: @davidm yes they would.